# Multiple Questions about Alarms and Notifications?

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

So what my goal is to make my app such that at specific times throughout the day it creates a notification for the user. For this, I am using AlarmManager to set an alarm and then when the  alarm "goes off", it will create a notification. Here is how it is setup -

Class 1 - Create Alarm
Class 2 - Create Notification
Class 3 - Response from Notification

I have made these 3 classes because of using "intent" in creating the alarm and notification.

Here is my code -

```
cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 30);
    calintent = new Intent(this, NotificationMaker.class);
    calpendingintent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 12345, calintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), calpendingintent);
```

And it calls upon the NotificationMaker class where -

```
    notifintent= new Intent(this, NotificationReceiver.class);
    notifpendingintent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notifintent, 0);

    notif = new Notification.Builder(this)
        .setContentTitle("Time To Smoke!")
        .setContentIntent(notifpendingintent)
        .addAction(R.drawable.background_teal, "Open App", notifpendingintent)
        .addAction(R.drawable.background_red, "I smoked", notifpendingintent).build();
    notifm = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notif.flags |= Notification.PRIORITY_MAX;
    notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
    notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    notifm.notify(0, notif);
```

the notification is being made. I have a few questions regarding this:

1) Can I perform the two tasks I want to do without using multiple classes? If so, how? (Make alarm and notification in the same class).
2) Whenever the alarm goes off, a blank layout opens and then the notification is made. How do I not have the blank page open?
3) Is there any more efficient way to perform the two tasks (make alarm to create timed notification).

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see you are using an Activity to create the Notification - better would be to use a BroadcastReciever and start a broadcast with your pending intent with AlarmManager.

[See here for more details on BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)

Comment: I am not using a broadcast receiver. I was following a tutorial online and I didn't need to use a broadcast receiver. I am creating the notification in the class called by the alarm intent.

Comment: But won't using a broadcastReciever make it more complicated?

Comment: no - you are starting an activity again and a broadcast reciever is more efficient - and the code is not really different
See this tutorial for more info:
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html